# How to get relation name programatically

Tags: apex

I have two objects:

```
Inquiry
Patient
```

Patient has many inquiries so there is a lookup field on the inquiry object.

now here is my code:

```
Patient__c p = [Select Id from Patient__c where id='00QJ000000B4yXa'];
SObject container;
Schema.sObjectType sType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('inquiry__c');
container = sType.newSObject();
```

I need a way to get the name of the lookup field on the child object .

in this example I would need the patient__c fieldname on the child record

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)'s `getDescribe` method (from the parent object), then call the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm)'s getChildRelationships() method. This will give you a list of [Schema.ChildRelationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm#apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship) entries, each one providing the name (`getRelationshipName`) you'd use to query with, and the field (`getField`) that is the lookup field on the child object (it's an [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectField), so you may need to run a describe on it if you need more information.

---

```
SObjectField parentField;
for(ChildRelationship rel: Patient__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
    if(rel.getChildSObject() == Inquiry__c.SObjectType) {
        parentField = rel.getField();
        break;
    }
}
// Here, parentField is the Inquiry__c's lookup field to Patient__c
```

Comment: Damn, looks like you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do that starting from the child side using the `Contact` object as an example:

```
SObjectType t = Contact.SObjectType;
for (SObjectField f : t.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
    if (f.getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.Reference) {
        System.debug(f + ' is a lookup');
    }
}
```

See the [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm%23apex_methods_system_fields_describe) documentation for more detail on the field information that is available.

If you know the parent object (as you appear to) sfdcfox's approach is better.

(Incidentlly this describe API feels a bit strange in this area in that you declare the dependency at the child side but the parent-side has the more convenient API i.e. there is no getParentRelationships method.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the describe for Patient__c to get the child relationships, and loop through them until you find the one for Inquiry__c and get the field name from that like so:

```
for(Schema.ChildRelationship relation : sObjectType.Patient__c.getChildRelationships()){
    if(relation.getChildSObject() == Inquiry__c.sObjectType ){
        FieldTokenYouWant = relation.getField();
    }
}
```